# Unable to change search.max_open_scroll_context for OpenSearch 1.1

Tags: curl, settings, opensearch

After migration to OpenSearch on AWS, we run into problems and get this error message

elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(429, 'search_phase_execution_exception',
'Trying to create too many scroll contexts. Must be less than or equal to: [500].
This limit can be set by changing the [search.max_open_scroll_context] setting.')

I understand that the configuration parameter search.max_open_scroll_context was set to unlimited in Elasticsearch 7.x but there is a pre-configured limit of 500 in OpenSearch 1.1 we are using now.

I also found information that it is possible to increase the value of max_open_scroll_context using something like

```
curl -x "" -X PUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
    "persistent" : {
        "search.max_open_scroll_context": 1024
    },
    "transient": {
        "search.max_open_scroll_context": 1024
    }
}'
```

I tried so but failed.
Using

```
aws-es-curl -X PUT $ES/_cluster/settings -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
  "persistent": {
    "search.max_open_scroll_context": 5000
  }
}'
```

with ES = url of our OpenSearch domain endpoint.
The result we get is

```
{"Message":"Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."}
```

Any idea how we may increase this configuration parameter?

Comment: Can you share how you solve it?